# Normalization of rgb images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to remove the variation of illumination in two images. One of my approach is:

```
    1) There are two images im1 and im2. Extract the R G B content of im1.
    2)Calculate the normalized value for each content
    3)Reform a color image.
    4)Repeat the process for im2
    5)Compare each pixel and replace the content of im2 with im1.

Image_rgb = imread('aswathy_33_crop.jpg');
Image_rgb = double(Image_rgb);
figure;imshow(uint8(Image_rgb));

Image_red = Image_rgb(:,:,1);
Image_green = Image_rgb(:,:,2);
Image_blue = Image_rgb(:,:,3);


[row,col] = size(Image_rgb(:,:,1));

for y = 1:row 
for x = 1:col 
   Red = Image_red(y,x);
   Green = Image_green(y,x);
   Blue = Image_blue(y,x);


    if(Red == 0 && Green==0 && Blue==0)
        Red = 1;
        Green = 1;
        Blue = 1;
    end

      NormalizedRed = Red/(Red + Green + Blue);
      NormalizedGreen = Green/(Red + Green + Blue);
      NormalizedBlue = Blue/(Red + Green + Blue);

 Image_red(y,x) = NormalizedRed;
 Image_green(y,x) = NormalizedGreen;
 Image_blue(y,x) = NormalizedBlue;
   end
end
Image_rgb(:,:,1) = Image_red;
Image_rgb(:,:,2) = Image_green;
Image_rgb(:,:,3) = Image_blue;

new_image1 = cat(3, Image_rgb(:,:,1) ,Image_rgb(:,:,2), Image_rgb(:,:,3));

figure; imshow(uint8(255*new_image1));
```

This is just normalization of single image, which at the end crashes with a completely distorted image.Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong and whether my approach to this issue is right or not?

[image]

input1

[image]

input2

Comment: Not sure what you are actually trying to achieve, but if you want to remove uneven illumination, you could look at my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891944/detect-quite-brighter-spots-on-the-image/27893051#27893051

Comment: @Mark Setchell I have added two images to this post. These two images are same and are taken under same circumstances. But we can see that there is a color change in it and this is due to the difference in illumination. I want to remove this from the image so that both look alike.

Comment: How about `New_Image = rgb2gray(Image_rgb)` ?

Comment: @Jan...I want to do it in rgb itself...am doing some morphological operations in it. Because of these variation some of the image doesn't come well. I was normalizing the image after converting it in gray.  I guess without removing the effect of light from rgb, gray image wont be perfect.

Comment: what is the purpose of steps 4 and 5?

Comment: @Andrew I want to eliminate the uneven illumination of one image with respect to another. So that at the end both image will have same illumination. This is what is my requirement. I don't know whether am in right path or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. but two a few things. The error at the end is a typo `unit8` should be `uint8` also, because the image is normalized, the values should be between 0 and 1, so you should probably multiply them by 255

```
figure; imshow(uint8(255*new_image1));
```

I'm also not sure where you got your normalizing equations from. The pixel values should be

```
  rgb_sum = Red + Green + Blue;
  NormalizedRed = Red/rgb_sum;
  NormalizedGreen = Green/rgb_sum;
  NormalizedBlue = Blue/rgb_sum;
```

because in the normalized space `R + B + G = 1` for every pixel. Running this simple code we can see that using the sqrt(sum of squares) doesn't obey the normalization

```
%sums the normalizes R,G,B values for all pixels
flat = sum(new_image1,3);
min(flat(:))
max(flat(:))
```

For a true normalized RGB image, both min and max should be 1 (+- rounding errors) meaning all the color components add up to 1 for all elements. Using your code with the sqrt does not sum to 1 for every pixel

**EDIT**

Now that I better understand your question, you are trying to compare the two images (the red one and the grey one) and make them as similar as possible. I dont think there is a easy way to do this in RGB colorspace. One alternative is the YCbCr colorspace. Like RGB it has 3 channels they are *Luminance* (greyscale image)*red difference* and *blue difference* you will see that the luminance channel is nearly the same for both images. The real differences are in the color channels. Here is some sample code to show you what the YCbCrSpace looks like

```
sidebyside = [red_im,grey_im]; 

%converts to new colorspace
YUVsidebyside = rgb2ycbcr(sidebyside);

%display results
figure();
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(sidebyside);title('original images side by side');
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(YUVsidebyside(:,:,1));title('Luminance channel');
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(YUVsidebyside(:,:,2));title('Blue Difference channel');
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(YUVsidebyside(:,:,3));title('Red Differrence channel');
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited the code as per your information but still I get an output which has no information at all. I guess normalization is done to remove uneven illumination. But will the approach  will work with this kind of output.

Comment: Please check my edit and see if it fixes your illumination change