# Otsu's method thresholding making a 'shroud'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-thresholding

I'm trying to threshold an image using Otsu's method in Opencv:

[image: input-image]

Although when I threshold it, some parts of the picture are completely surrounded by white and creates and ends up in Opencv not detecting all the contours in the image. This is what I get when I do Otsu's method thresholding using`ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(blurred,0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)`:

[image: thresholding-the-image]

**EDIT:**
Some people have asked for the code I am using so here it is:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('Input Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
                               cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,81,2)
#ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
#thresh_value = 70
#ret,thresh= cv2.threshold(blurred,thresh_value,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Now it makes some checkered noise: [image: WOAH]

Comment: it's because of the brightness loss to the borders of your image. Capture more uniformely iuminated scenes or use different lenses

Comment: The problem here is the lightning not contour or threshold. Are you limited to this image? Do you need image processing in this conditions?

Comment: If I can get image processing in these conditions that would be nice because I can't tell everyone who uses this to go out in the sun

Comment: or get more powerful lights

Comment: Try blurring/averaging your image say 100x100 (which will remove high frequency information and only leave slowly changing things like the uneven lighting) and subtracting the blurred image from the original to remove the slowly changing things and leave the sharp details of the text... https://stackoverflow.com/a/27893051/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do not need to manually find a sweet spot! Let OpenCV do it for you!**

OpenCV has an adaptive thresholding algorithm exactly from problems like this, called [adaptiveThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3)

This function divides the image into multiple sub-images, and thresholds each one individually. This means that it will find a nice threshold value for each part of the image and give you a nice and uniformly lit image. See this [example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

Try this:

```
th3 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(blurred,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
        cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

**Update:**
Functions like these do not work perfectly out of the box. If it still creates artefacts like salt and pepper noise, you can try:

- Significantly increasing the `blockSize`. This can ensure that each block has a letter inside, which will hopefully mean the threshold will be chosen better. (e.g. Dividing the image into `25` blocks instead of `100`. A `blocksize` of `11` pixels is very small.)
- First apply a blurring filter to ease out the bad spots creating the seasoning noise. (With the image name `blurry` I imagine that you've done this already.
- First the simple [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) function to just removes some noise. For example setting all pixels above 5 *and* below 100 equal to zero. Then after that apply the `adaptiveThreshold`.
- Follow @Mark`s advice by subtracting a blurred image from the original image. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891944/detect-quite-brighter-spots-on-the-image/27893051#27893051) thread)

I hope this helps!

Comment: it makes a lot of salt and pepper noise that creates a BIG disruption in opencv and gives numbers like `5698 contours detected`. At least Otsu's threshold gives a good threshold in the part it actually gets

Comment: @Nazar, I updated my answer with a few more suggestions. I hope it helps.

Comment: Still gives the salt and pepper noise and now doesn't even detect the letters anymore :(

Comment: what do you mean by normal threshold?

Comment: The one you used originally (`cv2.threshold`).

Comment: and how do you add 2 arguments into one argument?

Comment: and I don't really know how to subtract the blurred image from the original(sorry I'm still pretty new to OpenCV

Comment: @NazarKhan You can fine tune the window size and weight, to get the desired output with lesser salt and pepper noise. If it is still getting in your way then you can filter the contours on the size to ignore very small contours which lead to salt and pepper noise, You can also try some morphology operations as well.

Comment: morphological operations helped, and I tried fine tuning it but now I got some checkered kind of output

Comment: which  stops anything except the edges of the image being detected

Comment: looked more into it and now I got it! Works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Otsu's method try global thresholding method.

```
thresh_value = 50
ret,thresh= cv2.threshold(blurred,thresh_value,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

change the `thresh_value` parameter until you get the result you want.

Get to know more about thresholding techniques please refer the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html).

Comment: I changed the answer. Try this

Comment: Now it either eats the letters up or does not detect letters in the middle. No sweet spot tried changing thresh_value

Comment: until you reach the sweet spot change the `thresh_value`.